# Show all current conflicts using tool

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, merge-conflict-resolution

I am sometimes having conflicts when merging two branches using subversion.

This is not a real problem, as I just have to look at the actual code and solve them one after the other.

But I usually don't want to solve them during the merge process, as tortoise wants me to do and solve them afterwards.

Thing is our codebase is quite huge, and it takes a lot of times for the icons to refresh which makes it quite difficult to track down conflicts quickly.

So what is the best/easiest way to have some kind of listing of all the current conflicts in a repository ?

Any idea is welcome, I can also use another tool or the command line as soon as the solution is efficient.

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is what I found to get around :

In whatever repo you know have conflicts, you can use 
right click->Tortoise SVN->Resolved.

This will list all conflicts in the repo, taken recursively all subfolders too.

Find a target that is big enough for you, and resolve your conflicts till the list is empty. 
You can even resolve them directly within the window is you wanna go faster.

Group resolve also works for elements in the same folder that have the same kind of conflict.

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

`svn status` will help you to see postponed merge-conflicts (which also block possibility to commit)

Extraction from `svn help status`

```
  The first seven columns in the output are each one character wide:
    First column: Says if item was added, deleted, or otherwise changed
...
      'C' Conflicted
    Second column: Modifications of a file's or directory's properties
...
      'C' Conflicted
    Seventh column: Whether the item is the victim of a tree conflict
...
      'C' tree-Conflicted
```

Comment: Thx. That's what I would have done instinctively on a Linux machine. I tend to avoid the cli on Windows, not to feel sick. :)